# Setting printer Share name programmatically

Tags: c#, printing, wmi

I've been able to successfully rename a printer using the ManagementObject in the System.Management assembly.

```
string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Name = '{0}'", printerName);
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
ManagementObject printer = collection.Cast<ManagementObject>().ElementAt(0);
printer.InvokeMethod("RenamePrinter", new object[] { newName });
```

Is there something similar to set the share name of a printer?

Here's a screenshot of the property I'm trying to change:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I can change the ManagementObject's properties directly. This is how I did it:

```
string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Printer WHERE Name = '{0}'", printerName);
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
ManagementObject printer = collection.Cast<ManagementObject>().ElementAt(0);

// The part that changes the printer share name
printer.Properties["ShareName"].Value = newName;
printer.Put();
```